# How to create a global HashMap in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, global

Here is what my initial definitions are , all functions are in server.js one file

```
var HashMap = require('hashmap');
global.user_to_Socket_Map = new HashMap();
global.socket_to_user_Map = new HashMap();


function makeOnline(username,socket)
{
    socket.emit("test","hi");

    if(global.user_to_Socket_Map.has(username) != "true"){
        console.log("Setting callee socket of "+username
            + 'socket ' + socket);
        global.user_to_Socket_Map.set(username, socket);
        getSocket(username).emit('test','hi2')
        console.log("Setting callee socket of "+username);
        global.socket_to_user_Map.set(socket, username);
        global.userInCall_Map.set(username, "false");
    }
 }
```

and here is my getSocket function

```
function getSocket(username)
{
    console.log("Getting callee socket of "+username);
    if(global.user_to_Socket_Map.has(username) == "true"){
        console.log("Actually Getting callee socket of "+username);
        return global.user_to_Socket_Map.get(username);
    }



}
```

So , the error I get is `TypeError: Cannot call method 'emit' of undefined
 at line 25` , that is `getSocket(username).emit('test','hi2')` this function calling.

But I have just set the value of the key username as a value in socket. But one line after it is returning an undefined. I have used the global keyword. But still getting the error.

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted results of your console.log's.  Instead of trying to store the socket object, you may want to focus on socket.id and use io.sockets.socket(id).emit('hello');

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a Boolean to a string. The function `global.user_to_Socket_Map.has(username)` returns a Boolean, not a string. So the check `if(global.user_to_Socket_Map.has(username) == "true")` will always be false, thus `getSocket(username)` will always return `undefined`.

What you want to do is change the check `if(global.user_to_Socket_Map.has(username) == "true")` to `if(global.user_to_Socket_Map.has(username))` inside the `getSocket(username)` function like so:

```
function getSocket(username)
{
    console.log("Getting callee socket of "+username);
    if(global.user_to_Socket_Map.has(username)){
        console.log("Actually Getting callee socket of "+username);
        return global.user_to_Socket_Map.get(username);
    }
}
```